# mongodb allows guest connection even when auth is enabled

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB Version: 2.4.5

Enabled the auth=true in mongodb config. I can still connect to the mongodb instance from a remote host. It does enforce the authentication as I am not able to execute most queries as I get 'unauthorized' access but I can still run queries to get information about the server e.g. version etc. I was expecting the server to deny connection without credentials when the auth is enabled.

Comment: Have you tried `bind_ip` option? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-network/

Comment: if it denies connections then how to do you connect to it to authenticate?

Comment: True. It needs to allow connection but it should not allow any commands that allows users to find out about server.

Answer (score 4):

Yes basicly you can connect without authentication but cannot do nearly anything. you can run `db.serverBuildInfo()`

`db.version()`

`db.adminCommand({ping:1})`

`db.adminCommand({whatsmyuri:1})`

`db.adminCommand({features:1})`

for example, maybe some other commands.

Which is seems a bit pain for me is that able to run:

```
for(var i=0;i++<20000;){db.adminCommand({forceerror:1})}
```

Which generates a bit of log.

I checked out the sources, and you can see this behaviour is kind of bug. The sources of the shell startup are in : https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/shell/dbshell.cpp

Basicly there are two type of test running against the parameter values given in password and username arguments for mongoshell. The startup checks when you provided a --password parameter and have not wrote a password after. And there is a check when you have not specified to start without db, and you have specified a username which is longer than 0 than it will try to authenticate (check line 1043)

`if (!nodb && username.size())` .

But that is all. If you not specify credentials at all, it seems will connect without even try to authenticate. I guess in the initialization phase it should be checked weather the process where we connect is running with authentication and force out authenicaion if it needed.

Comment: How can I block it? It seems like a big security hole to me. I don't want ANYBODY to know the server information. They should be denied connection without authentication.

Comment: You can use a firewall (which is anyway a good idea). Only give access for your API servers to that port. From mongo side you cannot block it. From my point of it is a security hole while somebody will find the way inside to make trouble once got in.

Comment: I updated my answer read the explanation based on the sources. This means no way to prevent. You would have to update the source of the startup script.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created an admin user?

> Authentication requires at least one administrator user in the admin database. You can create the user before enabling authentication or after enabling authentication.

From http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/