# Mongo bug - How to protect or authenticate my database?

Tags: php, mongodb

How can I protect or authenticate my database in MongoDB?

I created a user using the command line,

```
use mydb
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "root",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdmin", db: "mydb" } ]
  }
)
```

my php,

```
// connect to mongodb
$m = new MongoClient();
var_dump($m);

// select a database
$db = $m->selectDB("mydb");
var_dump($db);
```

But why I still can access the database **without** authentication? What have I missed?

I'm on MongoDB 3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongodb allows guest connection even when auth is enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605783/mongodb-allows-guest-connection-even-when-auth-is-enabled)

Answer (score 1):

This is totally expected, not a bug at all.
I am just adding text to Blakes Seven's above link and comment:

This is the guest user concept and does not impact security (see Blakes link: [mongodb allows guest connection even when auth is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605783/mongodb-allows-guest-connection-even-when-auth-is-enabled)).

This means: your data is safe, guest users can only access meta data. This concept is well known from other services (see Jenkins, see some CMS system etc).

Comment: so then what PHP Mongo authentication for? http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.connecting.auth.php

Comment: Have a quick look at the link from Blake: you still need the authentication when actually reading and modifying the content of the DB. But maybe we are missing some info here: did you try to write/read real user data without authenticating?

Comment: The idea of a "duplicate" is generally for other people to vote on or flag, or preferably that the OP actually reads the linked answers and realizes the question has been answered before and closes themselves. You could have just commented with the link if you thought that might bolster acceptance of the issue.

Comment: @teelou the guest user can only do enough to commit an auth, no more, that is what everyone is trying to say

Comment: Thanks guys. I did a mistake - I must run the mongo again with like this `C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --auth`

Answer (score 0):

I must run the mongo again

`C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --auth`

Then the auth works as expected.